# CORS issue on GitHub when running git-receive-pack

Tags: javascript, git, github, same-origin-policy

I am trying to make the following requests on GitHub using a Chrome extension:

```
GET github.com/<user>/<repo>/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack
POST github.com/<user>/<repo>/git-receive-pack
```

Doing so, I receive a Bad Request Error (400). My understanding is that the error is due to the CORS policy. Actually, if I proxify the URL using CORS proxy servers (like [this](https://cors.isomorphic-git.org)), there is no issue.

Is there any way of handling this CORS issue in the Chrome extension?

P.S. If I use the extension to make the same requests on GitLab (without using a proxy server), there is no issue.

Comment: I have already followed what Chrome suggests for [Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr).

Comment: Are you sure that it's a CORS issue? CORS issues come from the remote site's policy. If you're able to bypass it by changing settings on your end, it's probably not CORS. Can you include the error message you're getting?

Comment: If it is CORS, then the answer is you can't bypass it.

Comment: I assume it is a CORS issue on GitHub since I can fix it only by using CORS proxy servers (i.e. proxify the URL). Any thoughts on what else it could be?

Comment: If it were a CORS issue, browsers would be logging an error in the devtools console that explicitly mentions CORS.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks for the reply. So if it is not a CORS issue, can you please share your thoughts on why it works when I use the CORS proxy? For instance, I can make the following request with no issue?
`GET https://cors.isomorphic-git.org/github.com/<user>/<repo>/info/refs?service=git-receive-pack`